# I need the Regex to get exactly string

Tags: regex

I need the Regex that select only string1

```
string1: potato
string2: potato2
string3: 1potato
string4: 1potato2
```

Thanks

Comment: You might find https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre and https://www.regular-expressions.info to be useful

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clear and complete. Nobody wants to go to another website to find out what you’re asking.

Comment: What about `string5: potato;` or `string6: potato and tomato`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\b` to match the boundary (left or right) of a word.

```
\bpotato\b
```

Comment: Thanks you, but does not work with I would like.

regex: **[\b]{0}variable[\b]{0}**

Match results:
_**variable**_
_**variable**2_
_**variable**1_

Comment: Well, if you type something different, you will get different results. Try using exactly what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
^potato$
```

`^` matches the beginning of the input, `$`matches the end.

Comment: see my example: https://rubular.com/r/PCmUbnJI47FsP1

Comment: Depending on the context, this is probably the proper solution. That said, if the need really is this simple, literal string matching is probably better. Also, the _exact_ meaning of `^'` and `$` can depend on flags.

Comment: @EmersonOliveira, It sounds like you really need `{0}` for something. You should edit the question to explain more clearly what you're trying to do. Also you don't want `[]` around these characters, as they'll be taken literally that way.

Comment: Hummm, I simplify the cases, see: https://rubular.com/r/TowdKfQtv23UgA

 I need select only string1 **_variable_**, but my expression select string2 and string3

Comment: @EmersonOliveira Please stop changing your requirements. This answer is correct for the question as originally asked.